# How to install IIS Role at Azure automatically

Tags: iis

I want to install "IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility" at Azure Startup Task

`<Task commandLine="installSomething.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />`

Could you please tell me the command that can install IIS Role, thanks